# Is there any way to pass C++ concepts themselves?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

```
template<class S>
using Floating1 = std::is_floating_point<S>;
template<class S>
concept Floating2 = std::is_floating_point_v<S>;
```

You can pass Floating1...

```
template<template<class...> class F> struct TType {
    template<class... S> using type = F<S...>;
};
using X = TType<Floating1>;
//...
template<class S> using Y = typename X::template type<S>;
```

So what about `Floating2`? You can call a function that distinguishes a `Floating2` if you know that's what you're looking for, just like instantiating `Floating1<S>`; but how do you pass `Floating2` like `TType<Floating1>`?

I highly suspect that it can't be done, any more than you can pass `class` or `auto`.

As a possible use case, functions like `std::invoke` have variants that let you specify a return type. It would be great if that return type could be a constrained auto. Can any function, template, etc. accept a concept, outside of concepts/requirements themselves?

Or you could write two helper functions, one using the concept and one not, for each and every concept you want to consider. There has to be a better way.

Comment: `std::invoke_r` doesn't do overload resolution on the return type. It helps you convert the returned value, that's all. I don't see how you're supposed to use a passed in concept. Concepts are meant to be read by people. Concepts often comes with semantic constraints not encoded within the concept. How are you going to deal with that?

Comment: Yeah, what if you want to convert the result to a given value category, like integral or floating point? It seems reasonable that a function returning auto can return Floating auto, but extremely unreasonable that you would have to hard-code the word Floating and duplicate your work the next time you want an Integral or whatever. As far as semantics, how is this any different from templates and the semantics of types? My responsibility should be like in designing `std::invoke_r` - it should be thorough in validation, but faithful in execution and oblivious to semantics.

Comment: I don't understand. How can a function return `Floating auto`? A function returns something of type `A` (let's call it that). In some templated context you'd check if this type `A` satisfies your constraints, which is exactly what concepts are for.

Comment: Yes... you'd check if it satisfies your constraints. Manually. Exhaustively. Can you imagine doing that for a template on every conceivable type? It looks just as parametrized as that to me. As far as returning, I was picturing `Floating auto out = result; return out;` but I haven't experimented with any of that yet. Don't get too hung up on `std::invoke_r` then. Maybe I want a factory for lambdas whose inputs are differently constrained autos. I'll think of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, concepts can't be passed as template (or any other kind of) arguments.

> As a possible use case, functions like std::invoke have variants that let you specify a return type. It would be great if that return type could be a constrained auto. Can any function, template, etc. accept a concept, outside of concepts/requirements themselves?

The caller of `std::invoke` can already achieve the exact same behavior that this would have at the call site, i.e.

```
SomeConcept auto ret = std::invoke(/*...*/);
```

This will produce an error if the return value doesn't satisfy `SomeConcept`. That's all a constraints on a return type of `std::invoke` would do as well.

I suspect this wasn't considered as a feature because there aren't any or many use cases that would actually profit over the current situation.

Comment: Well not exactly, you left the context where it was supposed to be generic/parametrized and hard-coded a single concept in by name. If you were iterating/traversing with many concepts, or you were anticipating a user-defined concept, you'd be out of luck. But I guess that's me out of luck, because I suck at C macros and my carpal tunnel's flaring up.

Comment: "No, concepts can't be passed as template (or any other kind of) arguments." Could you elaborate on this or find a source? Thanks if so.

Comment: @JohnP I can't really give you any source on a functionality that simply doesn't exist. [\[temp.arg\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg)  does however describe all kinds of template arguments and concepts are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @JohnP The question is what your ultimate use case is supposed to be. What kind of function do you imagine where it makes sense for the user to supply a concept instead of e.g. constraining return types themselves as I showed? If there is no good use case, then it wouldn't be added to the standard. Allowing to pass concepts would significantly complicate templates. "_If you were iterating/traversing with many concepts,_": It is not possible to iterate over concepts either and again I don't see what use case could require it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting used to the concept, pun not intended. I'm still exploring what's possible with them so it's not easy for me to come up with a compelling argument for a change. Thanks for your help.